# Dual power input

Tags: msp430

I'm reviewing this Dual power system.

1. Why do systems need dual power inputs ?`
2. Are the inputs pulled to system simultaneously, or is it one at a time?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is no dual input, the source to MCU can be selected from one supply.

In this case the R184 is marked "NL" which likely means "Not Loaded" so it is left off, and only R420 is used to select supply.

Sometimes you need to be able to change how submodules power in relation to each other, maybe for different reasons, like different options, or that the proper sequence is not determined before board is ordered and it can be chosen after testing which is the proper sequence.

Comment: Further more how come There's no reverse protection diode?

Comment: @Kabangu93 Like I explained, the circuit has manufacturing time options to select which regulator and only one of them can power the MCU. You either leave off R184 or R420. You leave both off and MCU has no power. You mount both and the power supplies are shorted together. So of course there is no diode and no need for diodes at all - only one power source is ever connected to MCU after board is mounted with components. You could achieve the same with jumpers or switches.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the system. Usually you would have dual power inputs either for redundancy (one power supply fails the backup takes over) in critically reliable systems that can't tolerate down time. This also facilitates a repair while the system is "on-line". The other reason is usually for battery backup in case the mains power fails, a battery supply takes over (similar to a UPS).

Whether the inputs are used simultaneously depends on the architecture of the system and the application.

Comment: Further more how come There's no reverse protection diode?

Comment: @Kabangu93 That's not clear. Where are you expecting this reverse protection diode? Do you mean a freewheeling diode? That's only needed for inductive loads. Or do you mean a reverse-polarity protection diode? That wouldn't be needed if you can only plug the upstream power source in one way i.e. you can't hook the polarity up the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

**1.Why do systems need dual power inputs ?**

Usually to increase the amount of current that is able to be supplied. These are 3A power supplies so if your load requires, say 4A, then one of these power supplies would not be able to supply enough power. If you tried to pull 4A from a 3A supply typically you'd see the output voltage of the supply drop. Using the MCU in this circuit as an example (the output of U42 is labeled "MCU_3v3" so there must be some MCU down the chain), when 3.3V drops below the minimum input voltage the MCU would likely power down.

The dual supplies with their outputs tied together are able to supply up to 3A+3A=6A now. They share that load equally (perfectly in the ideal world, not so perfectly in the real world) so if again you require 4A total from the dual supplies then one supply is providing 2A and the other is providing the other 2A.

Other than just needing dual supplies to supply the required amount of power, there can also be reasons like:

Derating / Reliability -> running a supply at or near maximum capacity can shorted the lifespan of the device. Each supply in a dual supply system requires half the demand as opposed to a single supply system.

Thermal -> Each supply will self-heat due to inefficiencies within the part. This part is rated to 150C. Say you have to put this part in an environment that is 100C and based on the load requirements you expect that part to self heat another 50C. Your part would reach 150C an again you're stressing it. With dual supplies your split the load and halve the self heating of each part so they would only get to 125C

**2. Are the inputs pulled to system simultaneously, or is it one at a time?**

Probably simultaneously. Would need a little more context to say forsure but U25's input is supplied by 5V and U42's input is supplied by 12V. If i had to guess, the 5V regulator is probably powered by the 12V regulator so if that is the case technically U42 comes on first and then U25 comes on shortly after. There could be something going on elsewhere in the circuit that intentionally holds off the 5V regulator from turning on so there's actually significant amount of time between U42 ad U25 coming on. But I doubt it since the outputs are tied together so then U42 would backfeed into the output of an unpowered U25 which isnt good.

Speaking of backfeeding, it looks like U42 is powered from two separate 12V rails. D59 and D60 provide isolation so that they do not contend with each other but can still share the input current load into U42 just like how U42 and U25 share the output load.

Comment: Good catch in the other answer by Justme. Looks like R184 is not populated so in this case there would actually be no backfeeding into an unpowered regulator

Comment: Further more how come There's no reverse protection diode?